# Challenge to a chess match / challenge over a match

Tags: prepositions

I am wondering if the correct one is:
He challenged me to a chess match. OR
He challenged me over a chess match.

Comment: [It's in the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/challenge)

Answer (score 2):

It's "He challenged me to a chess match.", if he wanted to play chess with you.

"He challenged me over a chess match." would mean that he was raising a protest about a match that had already taken place.

Comment: Please don't endorse off-topic questions. This lacks research, and is hardly suitable for a site aimed at linguists.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Shouldn't a site aimed at linguists be named "English Linguistics"?

Comment: Have you read the aims of the site?